# Linkage error in GCC when mapping a function to a different memory section

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, linkage

**Purpose:**

I am trying to re-map some certain functions from DDR to L3 cache, which is programmed as SRAM. I am using GNU Embedded Tools GCC 4.7.4 as my compiler.

**What I do (which will lead to my question):**

```
void __attribute__ ((noinline, section ("msmc_program"))) my_func1(unsigned int param0) {
//function body
}
```

This works with most of the functions. It compiles successfully and I can confirm the mapping from the map file.

However, my problem is that I failed to compile with some other functions. There is a linkage error:

**arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Section has no contents
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

**Question:**

What is the cause of this linkage error (final link failed: Section has no contents)? I provided some extra informations below.

When I check the code, I see that those functions are used in a constant table and called as a callback function.

This is what I do:

constant_table_file.h:

```
struct job_element_info_table_s
 {
    const unsigned int                          (* jeit_job_exec_func)();
 };
```

constant_table_file.c :

```
extern void __attribute__ ((externally_visible, long_call, noinline, section ("msmc_program"))) my_func_2(unsigned int param0);

const struct job_element_info_table_s job_info_table[] =
 {
   {
       (const unsigned int (* )())my_func_2,                                        
   }
 };
```

another_c_file.c:

```
void __attribute__ ((externally_visible, long_call, noinline, , section ("msmc_program"))) my_func_2(unsigned int param0) {
//function_body
}
```

Atrributes "externally_visible" and "long_call" are my experiments with the situation since the DDR and L3 cache addresses are far to each other. But I had no luck with them or without them.

I also tried to map the constant table "job_info_table" into the msmc_program section, but still I get the same error.

Another interesting point is, if I map the function into an arbitrary DDR section, it compiles successfully. Example:

```
void __attribute__ ((externally_visible, long_call, noinline, , section ("arbitrary_sec_123"))) my_func_2(unsigned int param0) {
//function_body
}
```

In this example, it automatically creates a section in DDR called arbitrary_sec_123 and maps the function to this section.

My compile options are:

```
# Compile options.
C_OPTS =    -Wall \
-Werror=uninitialized \
-Werror=maybe-uninitialized \
-Werror=overflow \
-mcpu=cortex-a15 \
-mtune=cortex-a15 \
-mabi=aapcs \
-mapcs \
-mfpu=neon \
-ftree-vectorize \
-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2 \
-mfloat-abi=hard \
-O3 \
-g \
-flto \
-marm \
-fno-gcse \
-fno-strict-aliasing \
-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks \
-fno-strict-overflow \
-fuse-linker-plugin \
-falign-functions=64

# Linker options.
L_OPTS = -nostartfiles \
-static \
-Wl,--gc-sections \
-Wl,-Map,$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PROJ).map \
-mcpu=cortex-a15 \
-mtune=cortex-a15 \
-mabi=aapcs \
-mapcs \
-mfpu=neon \
-ftree-vectorize \
-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2 \
-mfloat-abi=hard \
-O3 \
-g \
-flto \
-marm \
-fno-gcse \
-fno-strict-aliasing \
-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks \
-fno-strict-overflow \
-fuse-linker-plugin \
-falign-functions=64

LIBS = -lgcc -lc -lm -lrdimon
```

Comment: You cannot use cache like regular memory. It is managed by the hardware automatically and one cache-line can hold the contents of different addresses (not at the same time, of course).

Comment: This is actually a memory unit called Multicore Shared Memory and I can use it like a SRAM. I have already some data structures mapped to this memory. But I am trying to use a free section of it like a program memory. Regardless, there are caches in some architectures that you can use like a "regular memory", if you configure the cache like as a SRAM.

Comment: But you have to configure it to work as SRAM. So with regard to the question it is not a cache anymore. Presuming your problem is not the configuration, in which case more information is required. Also note that your gcc is quite outdated. Especially the ARM support has quite advanced in newer versions, but also LTO has some problems in this version.

Comment: I will try with the new version and share the results here.

Comment: Just to state this clear: I did not say this will remove the problem. It is just a good idea in general.